# What is the right syntax for an IAM policy to add to AWS Secret Manager to restrict access by IP

Tags: json, amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, aws-secrets-manager

I am creating a Secret in AWS secret manager and I try to put in a policy to restrict access by IP.
I do it under the Secret console in [Resource Permissions] section.
I keep getting syntax error, but not what is the error.
Here is the policy I am trying ( was create via the visual editor in AWS console).

```
 {
    "Version":"2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [{
            "Sid": "VisualEditor1",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "secretsmanager:*",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:secretsmanager:us-east-2:722317156788:secret:dev/playAround/junju-MWTXvg",
            "Condition": {
                "IpAddress": {
                    "aws:SourceIp": "210.75.12.75/32"
                }
            }
        }]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works after making two changes as below:

- remove leading space in front of opening brace "{" on the first line of policy
- for resource based policies, Principal is required (in certain circumstances)

Please refer to the attached picture of your updated policy to resolve the issue.

[image]